# Adding an Element to XML SQL 2008 Query

Tags: sql-server, xml, bcp

I am trying to add in a few elements in between the ROOT and PATH in a MSSQL 2008 Query.  For Example I generate this something like this:

```
<Employees>
  <Employee ID="1">
    <LastName>David</LastName>
    <FirstName>Larry</FirstName>
    <Title>Writer</Title>
  </Employee>
  <Employee ID="2">
    <LastName>Colbert</LastName>
    <FirstName>Stephen</FirstName>
    <Title>President of South Carolina</Title>
  </Employee>
```

With

```
SELECT 
    [EmployeeID] AS '@ID',
    [LastName], [FirstName],
    [Title]
FROM 
    [dbo].[Employees]
FOR XML PATH('Employee'), ROOT('Employees')
```

I'd like to add a few elements like this:

```
<Employees>
<Company>ACME DYNAMITE</Company>
<CreateDate>JAN 01 2013</CreateDate>
  <Employee ID="1">
    <LastName>David</LastName>
    <FirstName>Larry</FirstName>
    <Title>Writer</Title>
  </Employee>
  <Employee ID="2">
    <LastName>Colbert</LastName>
    <FirstName>Stephen</FirstName>
    <Title>President of South Carolina</Title>
 </Employee>
```

I am using BCP to generate an output file so it would be possible to append a header and footer to the output file.  If its possible in the query I'd like to do it that way. I have tried a variety of syntax but just can't seem to get it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  'ACME DYNAMITE' as Company,
  'JAN 01 2013' as CreateDate,
  (  
    SELECT
      [EmployeeID] AS '@ID',
      [LastName], 
      [FirstName],
      [Title]
    FROM 
      [dbo].[Employees]
    FOR XML PATH('Employee'), TYPE
  )
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Employees')
```

Comment: Thank you! The empty Path('') was what I wasn't getting.